# NodeJS module Syntax error on server but running perfectly locally

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-18.04

Here is the image of error that I get in console.

[image]

The module is installed on a NodeJS droplet on Digital Ocean. The droplet is `Ubuntu NodeJS 8.10.0 on 18.04`.

The command that I ran is:

```
tiktok-scraper hashtag myhashtag -n 300 -t csv
```

The module is: https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper

The above command is supposed to get 300 videos with the specific hashtag and save their information in a file. However, it only runs without error on my Windows PC.

How can I get it to run on the server as well?

Thanks.

Comment: [Optional catch binding](https://node.green/#ES2019-misc-optional-catch-binding) isn't available in Node 8. Given that Node 8 has now also [left LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/), I'd suggest upgrading. In general, use the same Node version for testing as you do in prod so you don't get caught out like this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can I upgrade the node version on Digital Ocean? How can I find the NodeJS version installed on my Windows PC? This is my first time use NPM and NodeJS. :)

Comment: I don't know specifics, I'd recommend researching around that topic.

Comment: sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nodejs - This should probably update Node.js. Otherwise, check https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04